# Dealing with a Generic Type cast

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, reflection

I have a generic type (RoleEntity) that may or may not implement an interface that is also generic (IActor). Background on the design
is below, but the short story is that a RoleEntity is a role that maybe assumed by an Actor and that RoleEntity *may* optionally
be an IActor with it's own Roles.

So if I want to access the Roles of a an Actor's role, I can think of two options

1. Cast the role safely to an Actor{T}. This is what I would do if I wasn't casting one generic to another; it *seems* the only way to do this is with some non-trivial reflection.
2. Use dynamic.

The code below is a bastardized mix of both. I am using reflection but not far enough to actually figure out the exact IActor{T}. Then because I have an indeterminate type I use IEnumerable{dynamic}. It doesn't feel like good code but I don't know how to do better.

Can someone present some cleaner code?

```
static void GetRoleHeirarchyString<T>(IActor<T> actor)
    where T : Entity, IActor<T> 
{
    foreach (var role in actor.AllRoles) {
        // do something with the Role;

        // trivial reflection
        var type = role.GetType();
        var pi = type.GetProperty("AllRoles");
        if (pi == null)
            continue;
        var roles = pi.GetValue(role, null) as IEnumerable<dynamic>;    // dynamic
        foreach (var r in roles) {
            // do something with the Role;
        }
    }
}
```

## Backround

Below are two interfaces that are part of a solution implementing [Roles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role_Class_Model).
In this design, a class that might be expressed as one or more Roles is called an Actor. The class that is expressing a Role (called a 'Role'!) 
uses an instance of the Actor to forward properties of interest from the Actor. So for example, if a Person class is an Actor for several roles 
in an application )ie, Student, Mother, and Employee) then each Role might use an instance of the Person to have a common Name property that 
is based on the Person.

Roles may or may not also be Actors; an Employee may be a ProjectManager or even a Buyer of something her employers sells. But a Student
may just be a role for a Person and not an Actor.

```
public class RoleEntity<T> : Entity where T : Entity, IActor<T>
{
    public T Actor { get; protected set; }
    ...
}

public interface IActor<T> where T : Entity, IActor<T>
{
    bool AddRole(IRoleFor<T> role);
    bool RemoveRole(IRoleFor<T> role);
    bool HasRole(IRoleFor<T> role);
    IEnumerable<IRoleFor<T>> AllRoles { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it is possible to define non-generic interface `IRoleEntity` and have your `RoleEntity<T>`implement `IRoleEntity`.

If you declare a method IRole.DoSomethingWithTheRole, then you can implement it in `RoleEntity<T>`.
And you can call it without knowing exact `RoleEntity<T>` type thanks to polymorphism.

Same trick you may want to do with `IActor<T>` inheriting `IActor`.

It doesn't always make sense, but I don't have enough understanding of your problem.

Comment: Yeah I agree. I actually just want to call RoleEntity.ToString() in this particular method. Then I just got caught up in the generic casting / dynamic side of the problem and wanted to see how to do that. I *could* also avoid the problem by making the RoleEntity.Actor an object and casting in each subclass but not ready to do that yet. Cheers!